# how to enable xattr support in Debian 9 (Stretch)

Tags: debian, ext4, fstab, xattr

I have added user_xattr in ext4 but when I remount it doesn't show xattr & I installed attr & attr_dev

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/Anonymous--vg-root /               ext4\040remount,user_xattr    errors=remount-ro 0       1`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User extended attributes are supported by default on Ext4, you don’t need to do anything to enable them. To verify this, run

```
cd
touch xattr-test
setfattr -n user.test -v "hello" xattr-test
getfattr xattr-test
```

This should show that the extended attribute was successfully stored.

Comment: Not working here, bare debian 9.5 server install, no desktop. setfattr was not even there. Installed attr. attr_dev unknown by apt. setfattr: test: Operation not supported

Comment: Found it's attr-dev, not attr_dev, but after installing it it keeps not working. Try as root: truncate -s 100M /tmp/test-bd; mkfs.ext4 /tmp/test-bd; mount -o user_xattr /tmp/test-bd /mnt; touch /mnt/test-file; setfattr -n hola -v lola /mnt/test-file; umount /mnt; rm /tmp/test-bd

Comment: @Toni you need to specify the namespace to use, `user` in this case: `setfattr -n user.hola -v lola /mnt/test-file`. See [`man 5 attr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/attr.5.html) for details.